# Crop 40/60 with ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I know how to use `-crop 50%x100%` to split an image in half (50/50) but is there a way to crop into 40/60?

If I use

```
convert -crop 40%x100% in.jpg out.jpg
```

I end up getting:

```
out-0.jpg // 40%
out-1.jpg // 40%
out-2.jpg // remaining %
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
convert in.jpg -gravity west -crop 40%x100% +repage out1.jpg
convert in.jpg -gravity east -crop 60%x100% +repage out2.jpg
```

I'm sure there is a more complex way, but I would just do it in two commands.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a single command like this:

```
convert in.jpg                                                               \
  \( +clone -gravity east -crop 60x100% +repage +write east.jpg +delete \)   \
  -gravity west -crop 40x100% +repage west.jpg
```